# Stop at beginning of a word on `forward-word`

Tags: motion

I often use multiple invocations of `forward-word` followed by a single `backward-word` to move point to the beginning of a word on a line.  I guess I never got used to the way `forward-word` differs from vim's `w` and even after years of using Emacs I cannot get used to the difference.

Is there a function I could use instead of `forward-word` that doesn't jump over words but stops at the beginning of a word as well?  Are there other strategies to move to the beginning of a word when moving point forward that don't involve repeatedly executing `forward-char`?

Comment: You may (at some point) be interested in writing your own forward/backward word/paragraph and related kill-word functions.  The following are three links to some custom functions that I use on a daily basis -- the behavior closely resembles certain word processors that I have used over the years:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/20456861/2112489 | http://stackoverflow.com/q/18675201/2112489 | http://superuser.com/a/685604/206164

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The `misc` package (shipped with emacs) has the built-in function `forward-to-word`, which does what I think you want:

```
forward-to-word is an interactive compiled Lisp function in `misc.el'.

It is bound to M-f.

(forward-to-word ARG)

Move forward until encountering the beginning of a word.
With argument, do this that many times.
```

To use it, first add `(require 'misc)` to your config file.

Comment: Thanks, this is useful.  Unfortunately, this doesn't *also* stop at the end of a word, though.

Comment: True, but neither does vim's `w`.  As far as I can see, there is an almost perfect vim-to-emacs mapping: `w` = `forward-to-word`; `e` = `forward-word`; `b` = `backward-word`; `ge` = `backward-to-word`.  But I'm not an expert vim user, so maybe there is some subtlety I am missing.

Comment: Heh, you are in fact right.  I guess whenever I'm in vim `w`, `e`, and `b` just blur away and I just move around.  Weird.  I was certain `w` stopped at both points!  So, I'll accept your answer, because it exactly fits my question :)

Answer (score 4):

You can bind the below function to `M-f` and bind the original `forward-word` to `M-F`. This function simply takes the `arg` and passes it on to the `forward-word` function. So the universal arguments will work just as fine as with the original function.

```el
(defun modi/forward-word-begin (arg)
  "Move forward a word and end up with the point being at the beginning of the
next word.  Move point forward ARG words (backward if ARG is negative).
If ARG is omitted or nil, move point forward one word."
  (interactive "p")
  (forward-word arg)
  (forward-word 1)
  (backward-word 1))
```

*Word of caution though that the above function might not always **do the right thing**; it's very much dependent on if the point is already on the beginning of a word or not.*

---

Here's another way of implementing the above where the *word* boundary is not as per the syntax table but strictly on whitespace separation:

```el
(defun modi/forward-word-begin (arg)
  "Move forward ARG (defaults to 1) number of words.
Here 'words' are defined as characters separated by whitespace."
  (interactive "p")
  (dotimes (_ arg)
    (forward-whitespace 1)))
```

*Credit goes to [**@glucas**](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/26098/115) for this idea.*

Answer (score 1):

After a long and painful search for the perfect 'forward/backward-word' functions I found the following with which I am now very happy:

```
(progn
  (defun boundary ()
    (and      (= (char-syntax (char-after))  ?w)
         (not (= (char-syntax (char-before)) ?w))))
  (defun my-forward-word ()
    (interactive) 
    (while (progn (forward-char)  (not (boundary)))))
  (defun my-backward-word ()
    (interactive) 
    (while (progn (backward-char) (not (boundary)))))
  (global-set-key [M-right] 'my-forward-word)
  (global-set-key [M-left]  'my-backward-word)
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to use `evil`,  `w` in normal state is bound to `evil-forward-word-begin`, which is the Vim-style functionality you're after.

Comment: I used to use `evil` a long time ago, but since a while I use `god-mode` and regular Emacs bindings instead.

Answer (score 0):

> I often use multiple invocations of forward-word followed by a single backward-word to move point to the beginning of a word on a line.

As you mention, the trick is to go two words forward, then one word backwards.

The following should do the trick and should respect other modes like subword mode.

```
(define-key global-map (kbd  "M-f")
  (lambda ()
    (interactive)
    (forward-word)
    (forward-word)
    (backward-word)))
```

This is a rudimentary version of https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/4272/508 that doesn't cover some cases, but easier to comprehend.