# forward-to-word functionality with subword-mode

Tags: navigation, subword-mode

I frequently type camelCase variable names, and enjoy the features `subword-mode` offers.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3931837/modifying-emacs-forward-word-backward-ward-behavior-to-be-like-in-vi-vim), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1771102/changing-emacs-forward-word-behaviour) and [this](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/4271/stop-at-beginning-of-a-word-on-forward-word) reiterate the fact that the community desires vim-like functionality where they can choose whether to go to the end of the current word, or beginning of the next word. One can use

- `forward-to-word` from the `misc` package,
- `viper-forward-word` from `viper`  or
- `evil-forward-word-begin` from `evil` to achieve the same thing.

However using these mean that `subword-mode` will be overridden. I am guessing that the only way to have both would be to implement a function like `subword-forward-to-word` which combines the two functionalities. I lack the knowledge in elisp to do so, so I am asking for your help. How can this be done?

Comment: The question is not clear to me as I am not familiar with vim navigation. It would help of you add examples to the question demonstrating how you like the navigation to be.

Comment: One solution is to go forward two words then back a word!

Comment: One of the other answers I gave the link to has the explanation for vim-like behavior: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3931837/modifying-emacs-forward-word-backward-ward-behavior-to-be-like-in-vi-vim

Comment: The [`syntax-subword`](https://bitbucket.org/jpkotta/syntax-subword/src/a1e0accb754d81e25b866b5ecfca5e1659e83580/syntax-subword.el) package (also available on Melpa) might be close to what you want. I haven't use the package myself.