# Move the cursor backwards to the end of the 1st word on it's between 2 words

Tags: cursor, motion

If the cursor is placed on a whitespace and there're multiple whitespaces between 2 words, how can I move the cursor backwards to the end of the 1st word?

Comment: Very closely related: http://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/4271/115

Comment: `M-b M-f`? Your description is not too clear ("first word"?). Try giving a concrete example, showing where the cursor is and just where you want to move it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could call `forward-whitespace` with a negative prefix argument. You can bind this to a key with a lambda. For example, bind it to `M-B`:

```el
(global-set-key (kbd "M-B") (lambda () (interactive) (forward-whitespace -1)))
```

Answer (score 2):

You could

1. move cursor to the beginning of the first word with `M-b` (`backward-word`)
2. and then move forward with `M-f` (`forward-word`), which place cursor after the end of the first word.

For example (`*` means point):

```
0: first    *   second
1: *first       second
2: first*       second
```

If you want always go to the end of the word when moving backward, then use in `init.el`

```lisp
(defun backward-word-end ()
  "Move backward to the end of the word."
  (interactive)
  (backward-word 2)
  (forward-word))

(global-set-key (kbd "M-b") 'backward-word-end)
```

P.S. But don't forget about `local-set-key` and `bind-key` if you use `package`.

Comment: A note that the `backward-word-end` function you wrote might not always work as intended.. What if the point is already at the end of a word? IMO, the `M-b M-f` approach you mention above is the best bet here.

Comment: That's how I do that now, but I don't want to anymore. I want to move it to the end of a word immediately.

Comment: I don't want to overwrite the default behaviour of M-b.